# Yii flash messages doesn't work after redirect if set custom sessions path

Tags: php, flash, session, yii

How can i fix problem with flash messages?
If sessionPath set by default, flash works good, but if I set it in config e.g.

```
'session' => array (
    'savePath' => '../tmp/sessions',
),
```

flashes doesn't work after redirect anymore.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must grant a proper permission to the `../tmp/sessions` path. For example:

```
chmod -R 775 tmp/sessions
```

Or 777. You may need to take care of the security issues of permissions.

Comment: Yep. Flashes still doesn't alive more then 1 request (must 2)

Comment: Dear @Stanislav, concept of FLASH is that, you only can use it once. After using a flash (getting it), the value of flash will be r-emoved. In other cases use `STATES`.

Comment: @AliMasudianPour you are not correct – flash message can be used any number of times you want. See [getFlashes(false)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#getFlashes-detail)

Comment: @MaugLee As Yii's official document says: `A flash message is available only in the current request and the next request. After that, it will be deleted automatically`. This is the concept of Flash message. however you can save it to use more than once by the method you sent.

Comment: @MaugLee As Yii's official document says: `A flash message is available only in the current request and the next request. After that, it will be deleted automatically`. This is the concept of Flash message. however you can save it to use more than once by passing false as delete argument.

Comment: Current and next request... it's 2. When session path changed work only current request, else current and next

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [getFlashes() method documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#getFlashes-detail) the method receives one parameter – to delete (default) or not message after calling this method. I think you want not to delete flash message after calling it for the first time. Test this for yourself:

```
var_dump(
    Yii::app()->user->getFlashes(false),
    Yii::app()->user->getFlashes(),
    Yii::app()->user->getFlashes()
);
```